# Error trying to access the email of a Firebase user

Tags: swift, firebase

This is my first Xcode project and I'm having problems accessing my emails from my snapshot values from Firebase. I'm using FIRDatabase to access my database on Firebase. I'm setting user to be a new User() class. And where I said there is a breakpoint error, there I'm trying to set user.email a value from the snapshot from FireBase.

```
var users : [User] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self

    let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
    print(snapshot)

    let user = User()
    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
    user.email = value?["email"] as? String ?? "" //Theres a Thread 1 break point 2.1 error
    user.uid = snapshot.key

    self.users.append(user)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Comment: Do you have a breakpoint set on that line?

Comment: How about `user?.email`?